# ScrollView not working with LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

The ScrollView is not working. I tried different combinations and no luck. Can someone point me out where am going wrong?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#333333"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <com.appsolute.ultimateproject.TypedfacedTextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.appsolute.ultimateproject"
                android:id="@+id/overview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                font:typeface="Roboto-Condensed.ttf" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#333333"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <com.appsolute.ultimateproject.TypedfacedTextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.appsolute.ultimateproject"
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                font:typeface="Roboto-Condensed.ttf" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_person" />

            <com.appsolute.ultimateproject.TypedfacedTextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.appsolute.ultimateproject"
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                font:typeface="Roboto-Condensed.ttf" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#333333"
            android:padding="1dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="1dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_fav" />

            <com.appsolute.ultimateproject.TypedfacedTextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.appsolute.ultimateproject"
                android:id="@+id/favorites"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                font:typeface="Roboto-Condensed.ttf" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#333333"
            android:padding="1dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="1dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_save" />

            <com.appsolute.ultimateproject.TypedfacedTextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.appsolute.ultimateproject"
                android:id="@+id/saved"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                font:typeface="Roboto-Condensed.ttf" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I have used fillViewport and also made the underlying contents to wrap. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Per ['How can I put a `ListView` in a `ScrollView`'? question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing) and the subsequent answer, `ListView`s handle their own internal scrolling and it is both expensive (from a layout performance perspective) and unworkable to put one scrolling container in another.

The easiest way to get around this is to use [ListView.addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) and [ListView.addFooterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) if you want additional items in your layout that scroll along with your `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

NEVER put a ListView inside of a ScrollView! Google for "android ListView in Scrollview" for more information. One example would be this one: [How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)